# FCPX Cross dissolve sometimes causes jump on stabilized video

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

I've seen this before, but I want to get to the bottom of it (I hope) so I can prevent it from happening again. I have a video with a few dozen stabilized clips. Looks good, though I want cross dissolves between each clip. That works fine, but sometimes going in or out of the transition causes a jump, as if the stabilization settings were different for the transition. For an example, take a look at this video... especially the start and end of the clip that runs from 00:31-00:43. 
http://dangoodspeed.com/shared/12n-downtown-schenectady-fire

Comment: When you're doing the dx, have the stabilized clips been rendered? IOW, depending on the order of operations the dx may be happening before stabilization.

Comment: Yes they were rendered before I did the dx.  One thing I noticed today is that the error happens when different types (inertia vs smoothcam) are used on the clips surrounding the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a crossfade transition effect, use opacity keyframes in the video animation menu. 
Select your clip and press "control + v".